# Random generator to mix two numbers of a predetermined list into one with 100 unique results

Tags: math, random, generator

I have 24 numbers (01, 02, 03, [...], 22, 23, 24). I need a generator that picks two numbers and mix them to one result (f.e.: 04 + 22 = 0422 or 2204). I need 100 unique results/combinations (no double results). Anyone knows, how to do this in a way which is really randomly (no manipulation, open source, etc...).

Comment: Is 04 + 22 considered a duplicate of 22 + 04?

Answer (score 1):

Make an array with values 0..575 and use [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) approach.

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from n−1 downto 1 do
     j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
     exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

After every step (execute for-cycle 100 times) get `v=a[i]` element, and transform it into needed form:

```
  xx = ((v // 24) + 1) * 100 + ((v %% 24) + 1)
  // - integer division and %% - modulo operations
```

then convert xx into length-4 string with leading zeros (like `%04d` printf specifier)

Comment: Why 576 values? All unique combinations are 24*23 == 552

Comment: @Magnus Bodin  I am not sure what author calls `unique combinations`. I considered that code must not give combination 0405 twice, but combination like 0404 is possible.

Comment: Yes, no twice results, but 0404 is possible.